How to upload Andriod studio code into a rev control hub (not wireless)
I'm trying to figure out how to upload my andriod studio code into a rev control hub using a wired connection (usb-c to usb a adapter) Picture of Screen
I've updated andriod studio to the new verion (koala), updated the rev control through the rev hardware client anc checked the connection, zipped and extracted the github code: https://github.com/FIRST-Tech-Challenge/FtcRobotController.
